# macOs Monterey UDP sockets permissions for socat

Tags: network

I have installed **socat** on macOs Montery thanks to **homebrew**.

The command:

```
socat UDP4-RECVFROM:8888,ip-add-membership=239.255.98.99:192.168.1.100,fork,reuseaddr -
```

doesn't retrieve any datagram (same command on a Linux machine does).

I have read that:

> For UDP sockets, the network entitlements restrict both initiation and
> data flow. For example, an app with only the client entitlement
> enabled can send, but not receive, data. Apps using UDP usually
> require both entitlements.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_network_client

How to give such permissions to **socat**?

Comment: Did you try with `sudo`?

Comment: yes: it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot give such permissions to `socat`. The documentation you have found is only for *sandboxed* apps. `socat` is not a sandbox app, and is thus not restricted in that area, and therefore you cannot give it permissions to "break out" of a sandbox that it was never in in the first place.

Even further, had `socat` been a sandboxed app, you're still looking at the wrong permission. That permission only controls *sending* out UDP packets. You want to receive them, so that's the "server" permission (`com.apple.security.network.server`) instead of the "client" permission (`com.apple.security.network.client`) that you quote in your question.

I assume you are aware that you are not "just" trying to receive UDP datagrams - you are also trying to do it using IP multicasting. Perhaps it would be better to open up a separate question to detail what you're trying to achieve as the end-goal, and solutions can be found for you.

Comment: I just want to use socat to intercept UDP datagrams sent by another machine on a multicast address. And I wonder why it runs out of the box on an Linux machine and not on my Mac.

Comment: I think you should open a new question and ask this instead. You have asked for something very specific regarding a certain permission, and this is not the problem you have. Open a new question, and we can give you advice on the actual problem you have. For example you could start diagnosing with a simple tcpdump first.