# socat UDP multicast issue on WiFi interface

Tags: macos, network, command-line

I have installed **socat** on macOs Montery thanks to homebrew.

The command:

```
socat UDP4-RECVFROM:8888,ip-add-membership=239.255.98.99:192.168.1.100,fork,reuseaddr -
```

doesn't retrieve any datagram (same command on a Linux machine does) on the WiFi interface whereas ethernet interface is fine.

What is the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [macOs Monterey UDP sockets permissions for socat](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438851/macos-monterey-udp-sockets-permissions-for-socat)

Comment: Good linking, but that answer asked for a new thread. We might need to close this for more details since it appears to be an XY question or series of questions where OP is asking about their attempted solution and not stating the actual problem.

Comment: This is the actual problem I believe... the other question was the XY question - so I think we should let this question stand as it is.

Comment: @Sylva1n As I wrote on the other question, I think you should start using tcpdump or wireshark to check what actually comes in on the network interface. Make sure you can see the UDP packets there first - and then bother with socat afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote on the other question, I think you should start using tcpdump or wireshark to check what actually comes in on the network interface. Make sure you can see the UDP packets there first - and then later you can get `socat` running.

The interesting thing in this question is that you state that it works on Ethernet but not on Wi-Fi. I'm assuming you're using a fairly recent Mac - they support multicast on WiFi just fine. To check run this command in the Terminal:

```
ifconfig en0
```

(where `en0` should be replaced with the interface name of your WiFi)

This should say something like this:

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
```

Note that it says "MULTICAST" - this is required for things to work.

The next step is to check your routing tables. You might have set things up to exclusive route multicast on the Ethernet interface and not the WiFi interface. In the Terminal run this command:

```
 netstat -nr | grep ^2
```

You should hopefully see lines like this:

```
224.0.0/4          link#5             UmCS           en0      
239.255.98.99      yyyyyy             UHmLWI         en0
```

Make sure that either the general route or the specific route exists and that it for the WiFi interface (instead of the ethernet interface).

You might also want to try changing the service order. Do that by opening `System Preferences > Networks` and then click the small circled `...` icon beneath the list of interfaces and select `Set Service Order`. Make sure your WiFi interface is listed before the Ethernet interface.

Also in `System Preferences`, you should check `Sharing` and ensure that `Internet Sharing` is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is Apple has packet capture tools already installed.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/recording_a_packet_trace

Why not use them to capture your packets and wire shark or another tool to analyze them.

Comment: How would that be the "main issue"? Nothing prevents you from using socat, and there's valid reasons for doing so that has nothing at all to with doing network tracing using tcpdump or wireshark. I.e. this is most probably to be used for an application (i.e. a practical use), not for debugging some existing network traffic.

Comment: I call em like I see them @jksoegaard sounds like we both recommend the same tools for this as the first triage step at least

Comment: Sure, but it was framed as an answer and pinpointing the main issue - not as a suggestion for triaging. That was just what I was reacting to.

Answer (score 0):

It was the internet sharing (in Sharing Preferences) that caused the problem.

Comment: Please have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers